# Descending order by date filter in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

```
<div class="recent" ng-repeat="reader in
    (filteredItems = (book.reader | orderBy: 'created_at' | limitTo: 1))">
</div>
```

So the book comes from rest api and it has many readers attached. I want to get the 'recent' reader.

The `created_at` field has the value which identifies the user as recent. But the above code gives me the oldest reader. So the order needs to be inversed? Is there some way to have the sorting in descending order?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy#orderBy-arguments) you can use the `reverse` argument.

```
filter:orderBy(array, expression[, reverse]);
```

Change your filter to:

```
orderBy: 'created_at':true
```

Comment: Note its `:` not a comma. (For other non-observant people)

Comment: If you wanted a sort button you could replace true with sortDirection. Then in your scope set $scope.sortDirection = true. The click button would look like ng-click="sortDirection = !sortDirection"

Comment: These is working only for the page that having complete table data in a single page, but it will not work for the pagination..

Comment: link to the documentation is broken

Answer (score 184):

You can prefix the argument in `orderBy` with a '-' to have descending order instead of ascending. I would write it like this:

```
<div class="recent" 
   ng-repeat="reader in book.reader | orderBy: '-created_at' | limitTo: 1">
</div>
```

This is also stated in the documentation for the filter [orderBy](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy).

Comment: Thank you, this is a nice quick and easy way to reverse the order.

Answer (score 41):

Perhaps this can be useful for someone:

In my case, I was getting an array of objects, each containing a date set by Mongoose.

I used:

```
ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy : sortComment : true"
```

And defined the function:

```
$scope.sortComment = function(comment) {
    var date = new Date(comment.created);
    return date;
};
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you. My date's were strings entered in a MMMM dd, YYYY format, and I couldn't figure out how to get angular to sort them correctly unless I used a method that constructed a date object. Worked like a charm.

Comment: This is correct method.. we can use this method in any date format.. thanks boss

Answer (score 17):

And a code example:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <ul ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'num':true">
            <li>{{item.num}} :: {{item.desc}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
function FooController($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {desc: 'a', num: 1},
        {desc: 'b', num: 2},
        {desc: 'c', num: 3},
    ];
}
```

Will give you:

```
3 :: c
2 :: b
1 :: a
```

On JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agjqN/

Answer (score 7):

**Descending Sort by date**

It will help to filter records with date in descending order.

```
$scope.logData = [
            { event: 'Payment', created_at: '04/05/17 6:47 PM PST' },
            { event: 'Payment', created_at: '04/06/17 12:47 AM PST' },
            { event: 'Payment', created_at: '04/05/17 1:50 PM PST' }
        ]; 

<div ng-repeat="logs in logData | orderBy: '-created_at'" >
      {{logs.event}}
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the orderBy is determined by a select box. I prefer Ludwig's response because you can set the sort direction in the select options as such:

```
        $scope.options = [
            { label: 'Title', value: 'title' },
            { label: 'Newest', value: '-publish_date' },
            { label: 'Featured', value: '-featured' }
        ];
```

markup:

```
<select ng-model="orderProp" ng-options="opt as opt.label for opt in options"></select>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:orderProp.value"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this doesn't appear to work with custom sorting functions.  Is there a way to reverse sort when using a custom orderBy function and selecting a parameter to order by from a <select> like in your example?

Answer (score 0):

see w3schools samples:
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_orderby_click

then add the "reverse" flag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<p>Click the table headers to change the sorting order:</p>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<table border="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('name')">Name</th>
<th ng-click="orderByMe('country')">Country</th>
</tr>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | orderBy:myOrderBy:reverse">
<td>{{x.name}}</td>
<td>{{x.country}}</td>
</tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Carl',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Margareth',country:'England'},
        {name:'Hege',country:'Norway'},
        {name:'Joe',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Gustav',country:'Sweden'},
        {name:'Birgit',country:'Denmark'},
        {name:'Mary',country:'England'},
        {name:'Kai',country:'Norway'}
        ];

    $scope.reverse=false;
    $scope.orderByMe = function(x) {

        if($scope.myOrderBy == x) {
            $scope.reverse=!$scope.reverse;
        }
        $scope.myOrderBy = x;
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My advise use moment() is easy to manage dates if they are strings values

```
//controller
$scope.sortBooks = function (reader) {
            var date = moment(reader.endDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
            return date;
        };

//template

ng-repeat="reader in book.reader | orderBy : sortBooks : true"
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.filter("toArray", function () {
    return function (obj) {
        var result = [];
        angular.forEach(obj, function (val, key) {
            result.push(val);
        });
        return result;
    };
});


myApp.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {

  $scope.logData = [
              { event: 'Payment', created_at: '10/10/2019 6:47 PM PST' },
              { event: 'Payment', created_at: '20/10/2019 12:47 AM PST' },
              { event: 'Payment', created_at: '30/10/2019 1:50 PM PST' }
          ]; 
        
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">

  <h4>Descending</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="logs in logData | toArray | orderBy:'created_at':true" >
          {{logs.event}} - Date : {{logs.created_at}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <br>
  
  
  <h4>Ascending</h4>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="logs in logData | toArray | orderBy:'created_at':false" >
          {{logs.event}} - Date : {{logs.created_at}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  
</div>
```