# ng-repeat and orderBy a String

Tags: angularjs, string, angularjs-orderby

I'm getting two items back from my API, one has a `startDate` and one has an `endDate` and I was wondering if it's possible to order them by their parameter string?

Data:

```
[
  {
    name: "Item 1",
    type: "Start Time"
  },
  {
    name: "Item 2",
    type: "End Time"
  }
]
```

Something like so:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: type='Start Time'">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Is is possible using Angular's orderBy filter?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks  good....is it not working?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261348/descending-order-by-date-filter-in-angularjs check this link.

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to specify StartTime,

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy: 'type'>{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Here is the working [`Application`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/b8cmfdje/)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to specify the key by which you want to order in your `orderBy`:

```
orderBy: 'type'
```

And if you want to reverse the order use `-`:

```
orderBy: '-type'
```

Comment: Will this work even if the data is flipped. And `Item 1` has a type of `End Time` and `Item 2` has a type of `Start Time`

Comment: yes, orderBy depends only on the key used to order by