# AngularJS - sort objects of dateTime string

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I use angularJS to show this list of objects:

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in vm.messages">
```

and message has a field time, this field has the following format:

```
dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss (e.g. 22.09.2016 15:17:45) -> string format
```

and I will order the message object in reverse dateTime order.
Is there a possibility to do this?

```
<tr ng-repeat="message in vm.messages | orderBy:'-time'">
```

does not do it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16261373/5621827 this may help (orderBy: 'time':true)