# To display first few items in rss feed at collapse state

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

My cordova ionic 1 code currently load all the rss feeds and this cause my page is too long due to too many rss feeds.

Thus, I just want to **display the first three rss item at preset(which is in collapse state)**. When **click on 'More',it will expand and display all items.** Click again, it will collapse and show only the first rss.

Currently, no rss items shows in collapse state. It shows all in expandable state.

What I required:

1. Display first three rss items, sort with date(latest on top) in collapse state.
2. Display all rss items when it is expandable state.

**my template**

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider">RSS</div>

  <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-if='showmore' ng-repeat="item in rssNews| orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openitems(item.link)">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <h6>{{item.pubDate}}</h6>
    <p {{story.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
  </div>
  </a>
  <div ng-click="togglemore()" <i class="icon" ng-class="showmore ? 'ion-android-remove-circle assertive' : 'ion-android-add-circle positive'"></i><span class="padding" ng-bind="showmore ? 'Less' : 'More'"></span></div>
</div>
```

**angularjs**

```
$scope.showmore = false;
$scope.togglemore = function() {
  $scope.showmore = !$scope.showmore;
};
```

collapse condition .Initial state.(Look at the '+' sign in blue color). None of the rss was shown. I want first 3 rss feeds to display.

[image]

Expand condition. It will show all the rss feeds.

[image]

Example, the rss feeds link is as below

https://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=KLSE:AEON&ei=pKh8WfndJ9G8uQTKgKq4CQ&output=rss

**another JS**

```
    $webServicesFactory.get(
      "https://www.google.com/finance/company_news",
      {},
      {
        output: "rss",
        q: 'KLSE' + ":" + 'AEON'
      }
    ).then(
      function success(xmlData) {
        var x2js = new X2JS();
        $globalFactory.personalStockNews = x2js.xml_str2json(xmlData).rss.channel.item;
        console.info($globalFactory.personalStockNews);
        $state.go("app.page");
      },
      function error(error) {
        $globalFactory.personalStockNews = null;
        $ionicLoading.hide();
        $state.go("app.page");
      }
    );
  },
  function error(error) {
    $ionicLoading.hide();
  }
);
$scope.rssNews = $globalFactory.personalStockNews;
```

In case you are confused with what is collapse and expand, this is the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/shengoo/6b0y3tar/

Comment: I think you have to set the initial max-height of the container to the height of 3 items in your list, when you toggle the expanded variable you set the max-height to a value higher thant it will ever get.

Comment: @David could you elaborate more or make an example in jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't have time right now to put something together but I think josh moronys tutorial on accordiion lists (https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/) could be of help (I know it's angular2 but the concept is the same). Instead of setting the collapsed height to 0 you can just set it to whatever value fits for 3 of your list items.

Comment: accodian list is working as you can see with the picture shown. It is just when it is collapse, I want to show 3 rss item sorted by date

Comment: Yes thats why I wrote "Instead of setting the collapsed height to 0 you can just set it to whatever value fits for 3 of your list items".

Comment: None of the part of the code is set the collapse height to 0. It would be nice if you can demonstrate in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/afagx45b/1/

I used the `| limit to x` filter of `ng-repeat` along with a simple ng-if statement on the div to know if show-more or show-less have been clicked. You should be able to adapt the rest to your needs.

When show-less is visible:
`<div ng-if="showmore" ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy: 'date'">`
and show-more is visible:
`<div ng-if="!showmore" ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy: 'date' | limitTo:3">`

Edit: Updated to show how to order by a date, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261348/descending-order-by-date-filter-in-angularjs) for more info on the orderBy filter.

Comment: Scott. Thanks. It works to show only first 3 items. But refer to my questions, 1st requirement, I need it to sort with date too. The code you shown miss that. Orderby, just don't work. Could you add on it?

Comment: That's pretty easy once you have real data to play with, just add in a filter to your ng-repeat: like this and point it to your date item: `| orderBy: 'created_at'`

ex: `ng-repeat="group in groups | orderBy: 'date'">`

Comment: Scott. `ng-repeat="item in rssNews| orderBy: 'pubDate':true"` from my original code has done the same function but it is not sorting. You can try with the rss link I provided above

Comment: ng-repeat="item in rssNews | orderBy: 'pubDate'"  you can use '-pubDate' to reverse the order. If you can make a fiddle that has the proper repeat with dated items I'll help you adapt it.

Comment: Scott, sorry. Try to create jsfiddle but unable to work. However, I saw the code in an example, but don't know how to adapt it into my JS. Could you help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497903/sort-date-in-rss-from-the-latest

Answer (score 1):

Angular comes with a `limitTo:limit` filter, it support limiting first x items and last x items:

```
 <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-if='showmore' ng-repeat="item in rssNews| limitTo:1 | orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openitems(item.link)">
```

you can find more info in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)

Comment: it shows one rss after expand, but when collapse, it shows nothing. What I want is shows all when expand, but shows one rss items when collapse.

Comment: could you show a demo? I'm a bit confused with the toggle()

Comment: It is simply a expand and collapse function. Like show more and show less

Comment: Sorry, unable to make my own. But this is a example of expand and collapse http://jsfiddle.net/shengoo/6b0y3tar/

Comment: create another simple demo. click on the more and less. It suppose to expand and collapse the list(it is not in demo as no rss items) http://jsfiddle.net/afagx45b/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `limitTo` as suggested by @marco gomes. You can set a variable to 3 initially which will tell `ng-repeat` to show only 3 rss items by default. But when you toggle to view more, then we will set the variable to length of the array to show all rss items.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="item item-divider">RSS</div>

  <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-if='showmore' ng-repeat="item in rssNews| limitTo:count | orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openitems(item.link)">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <h6>{{item.pubDate}}</h6>
    <p> {{story.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
  </div>
   </a>
  <div ng-click="togglemore()"> <i class="icon" ng-class="{'showmore' ? 'ion-android-remove-circle assertive' : 'ion-android-add-circle positive'}"></i><span class="padding" ng-bind="showmore ? 'Less' : 'More'"></span></div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
 $scope.count=3;
  $scope.showmore = false;
    $scope.togglemore = function(){
      $scope.showmore = !$scope.showmore;
      if($scope.showmore)
          $scope.count=$scope.rssNews.length;
      else
         $scope.count=3;
    };
```

**Working Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/6b0y3tar/190/

Comment: Hi. It is still the same as previously. Initial state(collapse) shows none of the rss. I suspect the rss items contents is not loaded at all. I guess may be a jsfiddle with the rss feeds is easier to view. Thanks

Comment: rssNews is an array of objects? Check if rssNews contain data by printing it in the view {{rssNews}} . Try putting debuggers and console to see where the code is going wrong?

Comment: yes, in array of objects. `$scope.count=3` does not work. If  `$scope.count=$scope.rssNews.length;` change to `$scope.count=5;`. It will show only 5 rss when it expand. So `$scope.count=$scope.rssNews.length;` works fine. I am not sure why `$scope.count=3` does not kick in when it is in collapse state

Comment: In collapse state are u using any css that hides the content, maybe the height of the collapsed view? Try inspecting the view if the data is there or not, it might be there.

Comment: Hi Vivz, no css that control the height. if your example of your jsfiddle modified to with the rss link https://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=KLSE:AEON&ei=pKh8WfndJ9G8uQTKgKq4CQ&output=rss, does it still working?

Comment: How to get the data in desired format from the above link. it is in xml I think

Comment: Vivz, I have updated the angular js that get the xml to rss. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Where is your $scope.rssNews?

Comment: Sorry, miss out `$scope.rssNews = $globalFactory.personalStockNews;`. Already updated the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150720/discussion-between-bkcollection-and-vivz).