# sort rss news by date with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, rss

I am referring a [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497903/sort-date-in-rss-from-the-latest) answer in JavaScript but I unable to work on it in angular js.

The javascript answer **to sort the rss feeds** according to the **date**(latest on top) is as below

```
data.query.results.rss.sort(function(item1, item2) {
    var d1 = new Date(item1.channel.item.pubDate)
    var d2 = new Date(item2.channel.item.pubDate)
    return d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()
})
```

My angular js (ionic framework) is as below:

```
            $webServicesFactory.get(
                  "https://www.google.com/finance/company_news",
                  {},
                  {
                    output: "rss",
                    q:  stock.e +":"+ stock.t
                  }
                ).then(
                  function success(xmlData) {
                    var x2js = new X2JS();

                    $globalFactory.personalStockNews = x2js.xml_str2json(xmlData).rss.channel.item;

   $globalFactory.personalStockNews.sort(function(item1, item2) {
       var d1 = new Date(item1.channel.item.pubDate);
       var d2 = new Date(item2.channel.item.pubDate);
       return d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
})
                    console.info($globalFactory.personalStockNews);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $state.go("app.home");
                  },
                  function error(error) {
                    $globalFactory.personalStockNews = null;

                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                    $state.go("app.home");
                  }
                );

              },
              function error(error) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
              }
            );
```

However, it did not sort as expected.
How shall I modified the javascript to angular js?

You can use the rss feeds below 
'https://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=SGX:533&ei=EeiDWaGGMpXUuATxloPgAw&output=rss' to sort the rss base on date.

In html, the code is as below:

```
  <a class="item item-icon-right" ng-if='showmore' ng-repeat="item in rssNews| orderBy: 'pubDate':true" ng-click="openitems(item.link)">
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
    <h6>{{item.pubDate}}</h6>
    <p {{story.description | htmlToPlaintext}}</p>
  </div>
  </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your sort function should look something like:

```
function(item1, item2) {
    var d1 = new Date(item1.channel.item.pubDate)
    var d2 = new Date(item2.channel.item.pubDate)

    if (d1>d2) return -1
    if (d2>d1) return 1
    return 0
}
```

Of course it would help if you stated what the desired outcome is in the question. :)

Also remove the orderby on your ng-repeat. That's overriding the array sorting you're doing in the controller.

Comment: Hi. I want to sort the rss link the latest on the top just like the stackoverflow example. However, I unable to sort it in angular js

Comment: Try your code, it is still  unable to sort. Perhaps you can try the rss feeds https://www.google.com/finance/company_news?q=SGX:533&ei=EeiDWaGGMpXUuATxloPgAw&output=rss

Comment: Well, I see one thing that's an issue. I updated my answer. I suspect your original sort function will actually work once you drop the ng-repeat.

Comment: Hi, I drop the orDerby but it is still the same. With and without orderBy, it just does not make any difference.

Comment: Can you post it in a codepen or plunker or something?