# Angularjs moving tr depending on current time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm looking for a way to implement a moving table-row to indicate my current time in a table with timestamps.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="timestamp in timestampArray">
        <td>{{timestamp}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Current table:

[image]

What i want to achieve:

[image]

The table-row with "NOW" should move automatically according to the current time.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: create a filter

Comment: You can save the current time in the controller, and then in the view you can do something like `{{timestamp == currentTimestamp ? "NOW" : timestamp}}`

Comment: app.filter('nowFilter', function() {
        return function(input) {
          return (input == new Date()) ? 'Now': input;
        }
    });

Answer (score 1):

you can compare your ng-repeat timestamp value to today's timestamp value and can handle this by using ng-if.

like

```
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="timestamp in timestampArray">
 <td>{{timestamp}}</td>
            <td ng-if="timestamp == todaytimestamp">Now</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Reading this question again, i'm not completely sure this is what the OP mean, because in the current table there there are 4 rows, and in the  desired outhup there are suddenly 5 rows

Comment: so basically we could remove the not condition from the ng-if statement. so whenever the timestamp matches today's timestamp now  <td> will display.

Comment: Perhaps.. If the OP could clarify this, then we'll know for sure. But your solution should work perfectly

Comment: yeah let's see. if not we can handle this other way around.

Comment: basically I want a separator with all timestamp before the current time above it, and all timestamps after the current time under it. This separator should move according to the current time ofcourse

Comment: why not using order by in ng-repeat! you can have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261348/descending-order-by-date-filter-in-angularjs

Comment: ordering this by timestamp it will automatically update the table and will also display the NOW <td> in a proper place.